# Session directory growing despite deleting files

Tags: unix, ls, rm

One of my servers has clearly had a buggy session garbage collection routine. The result is that the session dir contains millions on files. Deleting these will take weeks, but it seems like the session folder is growing faster than files are deleted.

I am deleting files in batches of 50000, which seems pretty efficient - takes about 5 mins.

> ls -U -1 | head -n 50000 | xargs rm -f

Still, when I do a directory list (ls -l) the session dir appears to be constantly growing.

> drwx-wx-wt 2 root root 843493376 Mar  6 15:36 session
>
> drwx-wx-wt 2 root root 843530240 Mar  6 15:41 session

So my question is: Is the directory actually growing (despite deleting 50000 files from it during the same timespan) or is the ls command outputting data from another source?

**UPDATE**

As also suggested in the comments, I moved the session directory that was growing out of hand. With a new empty session directory and some changes to the session clean-up script, this looks like it is working just fine now.

Removing the old session directory is still a bit of a task and since I do not know how many files are in the directory, it is difficult to say when it will be empty.

I realised that deleting a lage batch of files was impeding the performance of the server, so I reduced the batch size and wrote a small script for it.

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanSession(){
    nice -n 19 ls /var/lib/php/session_old -U -1 | head -n 1000 | xargs -I '{}' rm -f /var/lib/php/session_old/'{}'
    sleep 1
    cleanSession
}

cleanSession
```

Running this empties the directory in 1000 file batches. Using "df .", it looks like it is working slowly.

> Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/sda3            236764896  47035860 177702004  21% /

...

> /dev/sda3            236764896  47019528 177718336  21% /

Still, when I list the session folders there is no difference in the folder size of the old session dir. It is as if the folder size only expands to a max value.

Since it looks like the situation is solved, the answer is less important, but out of curiosity I would be interested in knowing how the folder size is calculated and why it does not decrease.

Comment: Why don't you move this directory out of the way, replace it with a brand new `session` directory, and see how fast the new `session` directory starts accumulating files?

Comment: And then fix whatever is making all those sessions... Perhaps make it so the application that creates a session is responsible to clean it up when it's done...

Comment: I did actually move the directory and so I now have a session dir, which is properly maintained and and a colossus of a directory with all the old sessions. Still, if I delete 50000 files from this directory and type "ls -l" the folder size is not changed, which was actually my question. How is the folder size reported by ls determined?

Comment: That depends on the file system. Many file systems will not automatically shrink a directory, even if you remove all the files from it. Some do, though...

Comment: Looking at your update - it's likely that the `ls`, which has to read through the entire directory on each iteration, is actually what's slowing this down (that and forking `rm` for every single file). I would just do `ionice -c3 nice -19 rm -rf /var/lib/php/session_old`, perhaps after-hours if completely minimizing I/O performance issues is necessary. But `ionice -c3` will put it in the "when the disk is idle" category...

Answer (score 0):

You could have used "rm -rf dirName" to remove all the files in that directory, but that would have had the performance impact you already noticed.

So, once your directory is empty, just remove it. The space used by it will be recovered.

You should understand that a directory is simply a special file. As you add files, it grows, if you remove some files, their spot will be marked empty and used my newly added files until there is no more empty spots. So right now all you are doing is marking all those millions of spots as "empty". They will never be removed until you remove the directory. It will have little impact on performance once the directory is empty. No more impact than deleting a single large file.